# scala - different ways to define a function

Tags: scala, function, lambda, definition

I am trying to better understand Scala syntax and different ways to write code, some cases are not very clear to me like  how lambda or function definition/call works.

For example, the same function with same result can be declared in several ways:

```
def foo: (Double,Double) => Double = (x,y) => x*y
  //> foo: => (Double#1671, Double#1671) => Double#1671
def foo = (x: Double,y : Double) => x*y
 //> foo: => (Double#1671, Double#1671) => Double#1671
def foo(x: Double, y: Double) = {(x * y) }
 //> foo: (x#722938: Double#1671, y#722939: Double#1671)Double#1671
```

all versions can be called same way and producing the same result:
   println( foo1(4,2) )  // 8.0

I would like to use this foo function as a reducer that will be used to operate in a list.

How should a reduce function that users a list like `list(1,2,3,4,...)` and `foo` as a reducer be implemented?  `//this case would output 24`

What are actually the possible usages and the pros & cons?

Comment: There are numerous questions about this already.

Answer (score -1):

As you had mentioned there are numerous ways we can implement foo in Scala. Infact it can written below as well:

```
val s = (x: Double, y: Double) => x*y
```

To implement foo as reducer, it can written in following ways:

```
def foo(x: List[Int]) = x.reduce(_ + _)
```

Or

```
val s = (x: List[Int]) => x.reduce(_ + _)
```